# 404 ошибка при получении содержимого по URL

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-404, spring-boot

Класс, который выполняет этот запрос:

```
package work.parse;

import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Places {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String run(String url) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Place")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "мой аппликейшн айди")
                .addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "мой аппликейшн кей")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
```

Как исправить это?

Comment: а где функция ?

Comment: Я немного подзабываю spring-mvc, но разве метод `run()` не должен быть публичным?

Comment: так было написано в документации, но сейчас попробую

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, 404 возвращает ваш контроллер или  ресурс, который вы вызываете (https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Place) ?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать из метода все и вернуть строку "Hello world".

Comment: это надо вьюшку писать, но мне надо только то что вернул метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю место `@RequestMapping("/")` нужно поменять. попробуйте следующее

```
package work.parse;

import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
public class Places {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String run(String url) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Place")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "мой аппликейшн айди")
                .addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "мой аппликейшн кей")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Regent если это класс тогда где сама функция ? вед обработку делает функция а не класс!!

Comment: не думаю что это так. Spring так не работает не хватает ModelAndView

Comment: не эт не то. Мне надо получить а не отобразить

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev, метод-обработчик в Spring MVC может возвращать не только `ModelAndView`.

Comment: Я понятия не имею как работает Spring. Но по поводу того, что в представленном коде описывается класс `Places`, в котором есть метод `run`, - я уверен. Это ведь Java.

Comment: @Nofate тогда получается, что @RequestMapping("/") не правильно поставлен

Comment: @Regent вы правы это java

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev почитал немного на эту тему. Как минимум `@RequestMapping("/")`, видимо, должен быть у метода, да. Осталось только узнать заработал ли код у автора. И имеет смысл _попробуйте так_ заменить на описание того, что вы сделали. Плюс вот это `public ModelAndView Places() {` так и висит в ответе.

Comment: @Regent сделал, спасибо за совет

Comment: да все работает. Для того чтобы посмотреть надо вьюшку писать, но вроде пыхтит что-то в стринг переводит.

Comment: @AndrewKolenteew рад что смогли помочь

Comment: Спасибо Вам за это)

Comment: Я всегда отмечаю если ответ правильный